# How to clone any component in React Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, material-ui

I want to set the values of the select fields which are selected and append a new select field with blank values. There are two functions which I have written.

```
this.state.paramCount = 1;

handleChangeParamList(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const str = 'paramSelect' + this.state.paramCount;
  const strOld = 'paramSelect' + (this.state.paramCount - 1);
  this.setState({
    [strOld]: e.target.innerText
  });
  this.setState({
    [str]: e.target.innerText
  }, this.handleCreateSelect);
  console.log(e.target);
}

handleCreateSelect() {
  const str = 'paramSelect' + this.state.paramCount;
  const strOld = 'paramSelect' + (this.state.paramCount - 1);
  const paramsListing = this.state.paramSelectList;
  const paramSelectLists = (<SelectField className="paramNames" onChange={this.handleChangeParamList} value={this.state[str]}>{items}</SelectField>);
  paramsListing.push(paramSelectLists);
  const count = this.state.paramCount + 1;
  this.setState({
    paramSelectList: paramsListing,
    paramCount: count
  });
  console.log(str, strOld, this.state[str], this.state[strOld]);
}
```

Comment: Since you posted your current code, tell us why it's not working. What's the expected behaviour, and what's the actual? Any error in console?

Comment: share your error if any